# Error 404 al intentar comunicarme con el controlador a travás de ajax

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, spring

Al intentar ejecutar el método callBuscarDatos me arroja error 404 y en la consola java me dice:

```
     Error del Usuario: -- desconocido -
```

consola web:

```
jquery-1.11.0.min.js:4 GET http://localhost:8080/Proyecto/DatosWeb/getDatos?rut=11.111.111-1 404 (Not Found)
```

Controlador

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getDatos", method = RequestMethod.GET, params = {"rut"})
public Response getDatos(@RequestParam(value = "rut") String rut) { 
    System.out.println("entre");
    rut = rut.replaceAll("\\.", "").replaceAll("\\-", "");      
    Proxy gAfil = new Proxy(propertiesFile.getProperty("GetDatos"));
    Request request = new Request();
    Response response = new Response(); 
    request.setRut(Integer.parseInt(rut.substring(0, rut.length()-1)));
    request.setDv(rut.substring(rut.length()-1, rut.length()));
    try {
        response = gAfil.getDato(request);
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return response;
}
```

Metodo JS

```
function callBuscarDatos()
{
var request = $.ajax({
    url : './getDatos',
    data : {rut: $('#rut').val()},
    method : 'GET',
    dataType : 'json'
});
request.done(function(data) {
console.log(data);
    if (data.condicion.codigoRespuesta === 0) {
        $('#dato1').val(data.info.dato1);
        $('#dato2').val(data.info.dato2);
        console.log("Correcto");
    } else {
    console.log('No se ha podido procesar la solictud');
        console.log(data.resultMessage);
    }
});
request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
    console.log('No se ha podido procesar la solictud');
});
}
```

Comment: Probastes si la ruta la cual te esta dando error en realidad existe?  `http://localhost:8080/Proyecto/DatosWeb/getDatos?rut=11.111.111-1`.  Veo que la estas mandando por GET, puedes colocar esa ruta en el navegador a ver si existe?

Comment: @DavidLeonardoMolinaRuizDav Me arroja el mensaje de seguridad de Spring y dice que no existe la ruta.

Answer (score 0):

fijate que en la url tienes un punto antes de la barra

> url : '(.)/getDatos',

a parte de ello intenta ir a la ruta, y tiene que devolverte algún dato, si no te devuelve nada o te da error es por que la ruta no es correcta, ten en cuenta que el error 404 es cuando no encuentra un recurso solicitado,

Comment: Traté de ejecutar la ruta de forma directa, pero la seguridad de Spring la bloquea, ya que sólo permite rutas con extensión htm, pero no puedo modificar esa configuración. Entonces leyendo algo de documentación encontré que si la ruta no contiene el pattern adecuado, se obtendrá un error 404. Tuve que ejecutar la consulta a través del submit para poder terminar mi trabajo a tiempo. Gracias por la ayuda, saludos. <servlet-mapping> <servlet-name>entry-dispatcher</servlet-name> <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern> </servlet-mapping>

Comment: me alegra saber que has encontrado una solución :D saludos

Comment: @TomásIgnacioTorresCalderón eso podria ser mas una respuesta, ¿Has considerado responder a tu pregunta?